# Joining 3 tables in MySQL gives duplicate rows with values

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I am trying to join three tables in MySQ, but when I do it my way, I get duplicate rows with incorrect values. and it appears that I am not doing it correctly.

I have three tables that I need to join:

```
nt_stentyper
id | tagsten | varenr_tilb | prod_type | dk | no | sv

nt_tunliste
varenummer | tunnummer | beskrivelse 

nt_priser
varenummer | pris
```

The data I wish to find is grouped by the `varenummer` in `nt_tunliste` and `nt_priser`. That `varenummer` is taken for `varenr_tilb`.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM nt_stentyper 
INNER JOIN nt_tunliste ON nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb = nt_tunliste.varenummer 
INNER JOIN nt_priser ON nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb = nt_tunliste.varenummer 
WHERE nt_stentyper.tagsten = 1 
ORDER BY nt_stentyper.prod_type ASC
```

... but that gives me duplicate rows like:

```
ID  tagsten varenr_tilb prod_type   dk  no  sv  varenummer  tunnummer   beskrivelse  varenummer pris_dk
1   1       12345678    1           1   1   1   12345678    12131415    RT 801       11111111   213
1   1       12345678    1           1   1   1   12345678    12131415    RT 801       12345678   200
5   1       11111111    5           1   1   1   11111111    11111112    Gratbånd     11111111   213
5   1       11111111    5           1   1   1   11111111    11111112    Gratbånd     12345678   200
```

... which isn't what I want.

The query should only display one `varenummer`.

Comment: the condition on the second join should have something to do with nt_priser, but it's a duplicate of the first join condition.

Comment: @mindandmedia: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the condition on the second join should have something to do with `nt_priser`, but it's a duplicate of the first join condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is because either of the tables used in inner join have duplicate values for columns used in joins.

To avoid this you can either remove duplicates from the table
    or use `GROUP BY nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb` 
or use `SELECT DISTINCT *` while selecting records.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting *, select only the fields you need. Something like this:

```
SELECT id, tagsten, nt_stentyper.varenr, prod_type, dk, no, sv, tunnummer, beskrivelse,     pris_dk FROM nt_stentyper 
INNER JOIN nt_tunliste ON nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb = nt_tunliste.varenummer 
INNER JOIN nt_priser ON nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb = nt_tunliste.varenummer 
WHERE nt_stentyper.tagsten = 1 
ORDER BY nt_stentyper.prod_type ASC
```

On another, unrelated note, I would highly encourage you to do all you coding in english since you never know if anybody, non-danish, is gonna look at your code at a later time :)